# How to detect input button value with jquery .on() submit

Tags: jquery, input, submit

How can I detect which input button is pressed on this form using jquery .on() submit?

```
<form name="input" action="none" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="user">
 <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
 <input id="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel">
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​



$('body').on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
      console.log($(this).attr("value"));
      return false;})
```

​
A jsfiddle example is here http://jsfiddle.net/dansalmo/suZHg/

I have looked many places and tried many different ways of trying to detect the input submit button value within the .on() method but I can't get it.

In my example $(this).attr("value") and $(this).val() come up undefined

I then want to be able to submit the form using ajax so just detecting the button is not the point of this question.  If there is no way to do it using .(on) submit then it would be helpful to know that as opposed to answering with alternate button detection methods that do not involve form submission.

Comment: You don't submit a BODY, you submit a FORM.

Comment: @Diodeus that's event delegation, so its fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any way from the submit handler to get this information, but you can get the information from the button click events and then use it in the submit event.

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
      console.log($(this).data('clicked'));
      return false;
});
$('form').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(e) {
      $(this.form).data('clicked', this.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suZHg/15/

Comment: This is great answer.  It explains that I can not detect the button within .(on) submit directly, but then provides a way to do it with a helper function using .(on).  Thank you.

Comment: I also like that this solution is general so it works with any form on the page.

Comment: If the form is place within a table, the $('form').on('click'... event does not fire unless it is changed to $('body').on('click'... http://jsfiddle.net/dansalmo/suZHg/16/

Comment: @dansalmo invalid HTML leads to all sorts of undefined problems.

Comment: I see now, missing <td>.  Thanks.

Comment: @Musa this is my code http://jsbin.com/nafiz/1/ and website when you click "report a problems" button and click a button from model,ajax not callback , http://downtimechecker.com/website/google.com

Answer (score 1):

You could intercept the click events for the submit buttons and then trigger the form submit manually, passing in a reference to the originating button:

```
        $("input:submit").on("click", function () {
            $("form[name='input']").trigger("submit", this);
            return false;
        });

        $('body').on('submit', 'form', function (e, button) {
            console.log($(button).val());
            return false;
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
      console.log($(this).val());
      return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**$(this)**  corresponds to the `form` here..

And not the `button` that had submitted

Try this

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('value'));
    return false;
})​
```

Comment: Yes, that part I was able to figure out.  Still don't know how to get the submit value from the button that was pressed.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts at answering.  You solution does detect the button value, but looses the form to submit.  I was hoping to get the button info without then having to do tricks to get the form info. It seemed likely that there should be a way within 'submit'.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input:submit').click(function(){alert(this.id); return false;});
```