# Quiz game: how to target the correct answer on the DOM and hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am working through a quiz game that imitates family feud. I have an input that a user types into and if one of the three answers displayed on the page matches that user's input the player gets the points and the answer is removed from the array and the same answer should fade away.

While it works functionally in javascript, I need to add styling to remove whichever correct answer was guessed.

In short, I'm currently able to match the correct answer object on the page according to what the user entered. How do I now access this same object on the DOM and hide its content?

Thank you!

- no back end
- answers stored in an array of objects in a js file
- using JQuery

edit: since I was getting crucified asking for how one would implement this through jquery I decided to use a function instead.

`correctAnswer` is an object being passed in.

```
  revealCorrectAnswer(correctAnswer) {
    $(".answer").each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() === correctAnswer.answer) {
        $(this).addClass("hidden");
        $(this)
          .parent()
          .next()
          .children()
          .addClass("hidden");
      }
    });
  }
```

[image]

```html
<section class="question-section">
        <h2 id="current-question">Question Goes Here</h2>
</section>
<section class="answers-section">
    <article class="answer-section" id="section-1">
        <div>
            <h1 class="answer answer-1">answer1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pts-section">
            <p class="answer-1-pts">50</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="answer answer-section" id="section-2">
        <div>
            <h1 class="answer-2">answer2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pts-section">
            <p class="answer-2-pts">75</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="answer answer-section" id="section-3">
        <div>
            <h1 class="answer-3">answer3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pts-section">
            <p class="answer answer-3-pts">100</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>

<section class="whose-turn">
    <form class="whose-turn-form">
        <p class="current-turn"></p>
        <label for="player-guess">
            <input type="input" class="player-guess" id="player-guess" name="player-guess" placeholder="Make a guess!">
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn submit-answer" id="submit-guess" name="submit-guess">Guess</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

```
$("#submit-guess").on("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (game.currentRound < 3) {
    game.whoseTurn();

    //let player 1 guess first
    if (game.currentPlayerTurn === "player1") {
      rotatePlayer(player2);
      checkInputOf(player1);
      updateTheScoreOf(player1, 1);
    } else if (game.currentPlayerTurn === "player2") {
      rotatePlayer(player1);
      checkInputOf(player2);
      updateTheScoreOf(player2, 2);
    }
  } else if (game.currentRound < 5) {
    if (game.currentPlayerTurn === "player2") {
      checkInputOf(player1);
      updateTheScoreOf(player1, 1);
    } else if (game.currentPlayerTurn === "player1") {
      checkInputOf(player2);
      updateTheScoreOf(player2, 2);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("|| Exceeds Rounds ||");
  }

  function rotatePlayer(player) {
    $(".current-turn").html(`${player.name}'s turn!`);
  }

  function checkInputOf(player) {
    let userInput = $("#player-guess").val();
    player.score += game.checkUserGuess(userInput, game.currentAnswers);
  }

  function updateTheScoreOf(player, domElementId) {
    $(`.player-${domElementId}-score`).html(`Score: ${player.score}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: You can fire a function reading the value of the input field as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201580/how-to-detect-input-button-value-with-jquery-on-submit So, can you share what you've tried within your that kind of function?

Comment: I only see a HTML structure, a nice image and a request. Did you try something ? If not, you should know we do not make code from scratch. At least not complex code without you trying something first. We help you debug/improve your code. If you want someone to make it for you, try some freelancing sites.

Comment: Of course I've been trying, I didnt spend the last week writing out this program to get stuck on this last feature. I simply have no idea how to make a connection to an object that is retrieved from my data and target the associated element on the DOM.